# Pyplot ticks at values divisible by automatic interval?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way how to force pyplot (matplotlib) to have ticks at values divisible by automatic interval of ticks?

I really like that pyplot can adjust interval of ticks automatically based on data so I don't have to care about it. But I would really like it does use values divisible by that interval.

For example if it decides that interval is 5, it should use values 5,10,15,20... and not 4,9,14,19 like in the example below. How can I easily fix it?

[image: Nice interval but not at divisible values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate your ticks anywhere you want using `matplotlib.ticker.Locator` classes. Specifically in your case I guess you'd like to use [`MultipleLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator). Just add in your program

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(base=5))
```

and you'll be all set.

**UPDATE:**

To get the base, you can check the default `AutoLocator` tick positions (after the call to `plt.plot`) and get the difference between any of them lying next to each other:

```
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
base = ticks[1] - ticks[0]
```

Comment: Thank you. My issue is though that I don't know the base by default. Is there a way to get the base from pyplot? The base is automatically set by pyplot depending on how many years are displayed. In this case it is 5 but it can easily be 2 or 10 or completely different numbers. I am looking for general solution.

Comment: You can get the base as the difference between neighboring ticks, see update